# How can I make a radgoll that keeps player's dead corpses

Tags: scripting, roblox

I've been trying hard for couple of hours to make is to that whenever player dies they radgoll and their dead body stays even after they respawn, unfortunately I failed hard to make it work. Any help would be much appreciated!

I tried making couple of scripts that cloned player's dead body but I failed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After the player dies, simply make a clone of their character and delete all scripts associated with it, this will create a dummy that will not despawn unless told otherwise.

Here is a code example

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        character.Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
            local clone = character:Clone()
            clone.Parent = workspace
            clone.Name = "BodyClone"
            for _,v in pais(clone:GetDescendants()) do
                if v:IsA("BaseScript") then
                    v:Destroy()
                end
            end
        end)
    end)

end)
```